# Node.js page caching

Tags: node.js, memcached, express

Is there a simple way to cache pages in Express, preferably Memcached? I'm using Jade as a templating system. I'm looking to cache certain pages for visitors for about 30 seconds. Preferably it uses `express.render`, but I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to handle result of rendering.

```js
var cache = {};

var getPageFromCache(url, callback) {
    if (cache[url]) {
        // Get page from cache
        callback(undefined, cache[url]);
    } else {
        // Get nothing
        callback();
    }
};

var setPageToCache(url, content) {
    // Save to cache
    cache[url] = content;
};

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    getPageFromCache(req.url, function(err, content) {
        if (err) return req.next(err);
        if (content) {
            res.send(content);
        } else {
            res.render('index.jade', { title: 'My Site' }, function(err, content) {
                // Render handler
                if (err) return req.next(err);
                setPageToCache(req.url, page);
                res.send(content);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Implement getPageFromCache and setPageToCache to work with memcached if you need.

Comment: didn't realize that there was a res.render callback (of course there is!) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a simple package: [cacher](https://npmjs.org/package/cacher), it's an express middleware handling page caching backed by memcached.

Example usage:

```
var Cacher = require("cacher")
var cacher = new Cacher("myhost:11211")

// as a global middleware
app.use(cacher.cacheHourly())
// or per route
app.get("/long-cache", cacher.cacheDaily(), ...)
app.get("/short-cache", cacher.cacheOneMinute(), ...)
app.get("/no-cache", ...)

// listen for events
cacher.on("hit", function(url) {
  console.log("woohoo!", url)
})

cacher.on("miss", function(url) {
  console.log("doh!", url)
})

cacher.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

See also the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/addisonj/node-cacher)